# How to find out whether a server is partnered or not ( discord.js v13 )

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am building a discord bot that has a server info command which shows info on a discord server and in the command I want to add a new field called Partnered. Is there a way I can find out whether a server is partnered or not using discord.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please check the [**documentation**](https://discord.js.org/) before asking a question as this can save a lot of time.

##### **Guild#partnered**

[DJS Docs: Guild: partnered](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=partnered)

On the guild object, there is a value `partnered` which will return either true or false depending on the partnership status.